# jQuery function not returning

Tags: javascript, jquery

(function($){

```
    $.a.b  = {

        title: "ABC",

        init: function (id) {
                 /* do something here */
                  return id+'a';

              }




    };

})(jQuery);
```

When I try to call $.a.b.init('t'); it does not work, I mean it does not return as expected. Any suggestions?

**The problem is not that $.a.b.init('t') is not working. Problem is that it returns the code of the whole function instead of returning say a string.**

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The code as posted works well, besides the `$.a.b` thing: http://jsbin.com/eqaji/ . Typically, you'll get the source of the function if you don't start it, e.g. `alert($.a.b.init);` and not `alert($.a.b.init('parameter'));`, so there isn't much more I can think of without more code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
$.a = [];
$.a.b  = { ... }
```

or even better:

```
$.a = {b: {
     title: "",
     init: ...
}};
```

When using `$.a.b` a is undefined, so you cannot add to it.

Comment: @Ramblingwood - invaluable tool. But even the error console can help here: Ctrl+Shift+J on Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

Since **`$.a`** is not yet defined you cannot set the **`b`** property. First you'll need to create **`$.a`**. Alternatively, use a namespacing helper:

```
$.namespace = function(ns) {
    var cur = $, split = ns.split('.');
    while (split[0]) {
        cur = cur[split.shift()] = {};
    }
    return cur;
};

$.namespace('a').b = { ... };
```

It can also be used with deeper namespaces:

```
$.namespace('a.b.c.d.e.f').g = 123;
$.a.b.c.d.e.f.g; // => 123
```

Comment: Interesting and weird. I guess if you use that a lot you can add it for all objects, not just jQuery.